Selenium + Java : How to Iterate the cells in a Web Table to Select Checkbox based on the text in another cells in the same row
I am new to Selenium, Learning my way into Test Automation from Manual Testing.
I am have been trying to iterate within Table to select the checkbox based on the value in the another cell in the same row.




Name
Relation
D.O.B




CB1
John
Staff
01-Jan-1995


CB2
Mary
Spouse
01-Jan-2005


CB3
Philip
Child
01-Jan-2000


CB4
Kaleb
Child
01-Jan-2024



CB - Checkbox
I am passing Nos and relation from Excel to the method. ( String Nos, String relation) - >
Nos as  String.ValueOf(Nos)
relation as Array - > Spouse,Child or Spouse,Infant or Empolyee,Spouse or Employee,Infant
then Splitting the Array with ',' separator  -
String[] paxsel = relation.split(",");

Expecting to click on the check box in the row where ( relation passed from the Excel == text in the Relation column )  along with condition ,
If Relation passed from Excel is Employee, And it matches the text in the relation column then Click on Checkbox CB1
If Relation passed from Excel is Spouse, And it matches the text in the relation column then Click on Checkbox CB1
If Relation passed from Excel is Child, And if it matches the text in the relation column then calculate the Age, And If Age more than 731 days then Select Child checkbox
If Relation passed from Excel is Infant, And if it matches text in the relation column then calculate the Age, And If Age less than 731 days then Select Child checkbox where d.o.b is less than 2 years
It should come out of the loop when No of checkbox equals to 'Nos'
Code snippet Below:
public void selectMembers(String nos, String relation) {

        String[] paxsel = relation.split(",");

        try {
            List<WebElement> rows = tblPassengerList.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

            int relationindex = 2;
            int dobindex = 3;
            WebElement paxRelation;
            WebElement dob;


            for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
                List<WebElement> cells = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                for(int j=0;j<Integer.valueOf(nos);)
                if (!cells.isEmpty()) {
                    dob = cells.get(dobindex);
                    paxRelation = cells.get(relationindex);
                    String fdob = dob.getText();

                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy");
                    LocalDate fdob1 = LocalDate.parse(fdob, formatter);
                    LocalDate currDate = LocalDate.now();

                    System.out.println(paxsel[j]);
                    if (paxsel[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Infant") && paxRelation.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Child") && calculateAge(fdob1, currDate) <= 731) {
                        WebElement checkbox = cells.get(0).findElement(By.tagName("input"));
                        checkbox.click();
                        j=j+1;

                    } else if (paxsel[j].equalsIgnoreCase(paxRelation.getText()) && paxRelation.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Child") && calculateAge(fdob1, currDate) > 731) {
                        WebElement checkbox = cells.get(0).findElement(By.tagName("input"));
                        checkbox.click();
                        j=j+1;


                    } else if (paxsel[j].equalsIgnoreCase(paxRelation.getText())) {
                        WebElement checkbox = cells.get(0).findElement(By.tagName("input"));
                        checkbox.click();
                        j=j+1;
                    }

                }
                break;
            }


    } catch(
    NumberFormatException e)

    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

    public static long calculateAge(LocalDate fdob, LocalDate currentDate) {
        long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(fdob, currentDate);
        return days;
    }

Either it throws Index out of Bound for Length, or it deoes'nt clicks on the checkbox.

seems like it's this: j<Integer.valueOf(noOfPax)  but you don't show where that's defined.  Best to just use length/count of array you are getting value(s) from.  (if it's zero, it will fail gracefully...)

@browsermator, My bad , I forgot to rename when posting it here.. noOfPax is nothing but 'nos'. I have edited n saved.

@browsermator , Still struggling to get the loop correct.

you are passing in nos... the count used for iteration should come from the array you are iterating.  (to avoid out of bounds errors...) This:  for(int j=0;j<Integer.valueOf(nos);)  Assumes the array will have a pre-defined length/count.  Use a foreach unless there's some reason you need the index for a check.  Don't mess with the iterator.  (here I think you've got some j++ inside conditions... put that in the for loop)

@browsermator, Thanks man, as u said, loops needed simple corrections.. It working now.
